# What does `input.Sum(b => b - '0')` mean and why does it work without defining `b`?

Tags: c#

I'm really a beginner at c#. I found this piece of C# code:

```
int result;
string input;
result = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Give the number of which you want the sum.");
input = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (char c in input)
{
 ---> result = input.Sum(b => b - '0');
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I'm confused by this line:

```
result = input.Sum(b => b - '0');
```

Could someone tell me what's going on in that line? It's using the variable `b` whilst it's not defined. And what does the `'0'` stand for?

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer it in few words. A good place for you to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: I understand the question is a little wonky, but his real question is what does `(b => b - 0)` do

Comment: `b`is a `Lambda` Expression and 0 is a `char` in this case. Lambda : http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda

Comment: To learn what b is generally read up about lambada exprsions. In the context of `input.Sum(b => b - '0');` b is each letter of input so the whole thing means: return the sum of, each of the int value of the characters - the int value of 0, of the string `input`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @sloef202: As a general recommendation when having questions like this: Take advantage of the tooltip and F1 and F12 (Go to Definition) support in Visual Studio, it really is excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on in the question for a beginner programmer, so let's break it down.

First, let's imagine you had an array of numbers like this:

```
int[] numbers = new { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Now, you want to add these numbers up to get the sum. The obvious way to do this in most programming languages is to use a loop like so.

```
int sum = 0;

foreach(int b in numbers)
    sum += b;
```

However, there's a short hand way of doing the same thing by using a lambda expression.

```
int sum = numbers.Sum(b => b);
```

The reason this works is because in a lambda expression, the type of b is can be inferred automatically. It is essentially saying b is one of the elements in the int array called numbers.

This can be a little confusing at first until you wrap your head around it. For a while you might need to translate between the foreach loop and the lambda expression in your head.

The second part of your question is about the '0'

What you are seeing here is the syntax for a character within a string. For example, let's say you declare a string like this:

```
string input = "Hello";
```

A string is actually just an array of characters, it can also be represented like this:

```
char[] input = new { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

It also happens that in computers, characters are just numbers. Each character has it's numeric equivalent. For example, 'H' is 72. See the [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) for reference.

And because it's really just an array of numbers, you can do lambda expressions on it.

```
int sum = input.Sum(b => b);
```

Finally, we get back to the confusing line.

```
int result = input.Sum(b => b - '0');
```

Hopefully by now, you'll understand what's going on here. The values of the characters in the string are being summed together, and at the same time, the value of the '0' character (48) is being subtracted from each element. Or to put it another way:

```
int result = 0;

foreach(char b in input)
    result += b - '0';
```

Good night :)

Comment: Your linked "ASCII" table is really a Windows-1252 table (which it vaguely says on the page). But, for .NET (and Java and HTML and JavaScript and …), you should refer to a Unicode table instead (for example, [FileFormat.info Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm) or [Unicode character table](http://unicode-table.com/)).

Comment: I just googled and pasted in the first ASCII table that looked reasonable. It's really just to make the point that each character has a number and for this purpose it does the job nicely. I agree that I could have posted something more accurate, but the links you posted don't show a nice clean table that demonstrates the point.

Answer (score 1):

`b => b - '0'` is a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).`b` represents each `char` in the input. It takes each character in the input then substracts '0' from them and returns the value. Here subscracting `'0'` is  a trick. Since, `b` is a `char`, it's converted to `int` and the value of the conversion is the `ASCII` value of `b`.When you subscrat the ASCII value of `0` you get the numerical value.

For example `ASCII` value of `2` is `50` and `0` is `48`. when you substract 48 from 50 you get 2 which is the numerical value of the `char`.

So this code simply subscrats '0' from each char, finds the numerical value and gets the sum of them.

Comment: `char` holds a UTF-16 code-unit, one or two of which make a Unicode codepoint. (The algorithm assumes one.) `'0'` is a `char` literal. Mentioning ASCII obscures these facts.

Answer (score 0):

```
b =>
```

is defining `b` as a lambda

```
foreach (char c in input)
{
    result = input.Sum(b => b - '0');
}
```

This for loop will take the value for`'0'`, from each character in `input`'s value.

You could get the same result with the following, which uses input as an `int` as opposed to a `string`. And is in my opinion easier to understand.

```
int input = 0, result = 0;
int sum = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Give the number of which you want the sum.");
input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while (input != 0) 
{
    sum += input % 10;
    input /= 10;

    result += sum; 
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, `b => ...` is a Lambda expression, which works for some input `b` and does something. In this case, `b` stands for *a character in input*.

However, the code in the question is actually wrong. What it is supposed to do is calculate the cross total (the sum of all the digits) of the number the user enters, so for input `1234` the result would be `10`.

Looping over the characters in `input` is actually superfluous, as the `Sum` function does this already.

The line

```
result = input.Sum(b => b - '0');
```

means:

> For every character `b` in `input`, subtract the character code of `0` from `b` and sum it up, calculating the cross total of the given number. Assign this sum to `result`.

This actually turns every **character** between '0' to '9' into the **number** 0 to 9 and sums it up.

Doing this in a loop is actually unnecessary and very misleading, as `Sum` loops implicitly. So actually, this should read

```
Console.WriteLine("Give the number of which you want the sum.");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

int result = input.Sum(b => b - '0');
Console.WriteLine(result);
```